# how to do scala pattern matching on array?

Tags: arrays, scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching

i am a new Scala programmer and I have a question on Scala Array pattern matching:

```
def countErased(sorted: Array[Array[Int]], acc: Int): Int = {
    sorted match{
        case Array() | Array(_) => acc
        case Array(h,n,_*) =>
            if(n(0) < h(1)){
                countErased(Array(h,_*), acc+1)
            }else{
                countErased(Array(n,_*), acc)
            }
    }
}
```

Basically what i want to do is: when we have an Array of length longer than 2, if n(0)< h(1), call function recursively with a new Array of the head and whatever as the tail. otherwise call function with a new Array of the next and whatever as the tail.
But this code gets me an error:

```
"error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((<x$1: error>) => x$1.$times) (in solution.scala)
                countErased(Array(h,_*), acc+1)"
```

What is wrong?

Comment: This is a perfect example of a situation where you should use a List instead of an Array, pattern matching has a few limitations, caused by certain implementation details and the way the type hierarchy is setup (and of course also erasure). It is possible to make this work using an alias and a type casting but it will just be very ugly.

Comment: Complementing @sinanspd this code is also pretty in efficient since **Arrays** are slow on all those operations, use a **List** instead. It would be easier, more beautiful, more efficient and safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate problem is addressed in the other answer: you just need to give a name to the splat, like `rest@_*`, and use that to refer to it.

I just want to second the advice from the comments, and mention that you should be using a `List` rather that an array (you can have a wrapper function that calls `countErased(array.toList, 0)` if that's convenient).

The `match` in scala also looks much nicer and idiomatic with lists:

```
def countErased(sorted: List[Array[Int]], acc: Int) = sorted match {
  case h@Array(_, x, _*) :: Array(y, _*) :: tail if y < x => countErased(h :: tail, acc+1) 
  case _ :: n :: tail => countErased(n :: tail, acc)
  case _ => acc
}
```

As a side note, one difference from your original implementation is that this one does not throw if one of the arrays happens to have fewer than two elements.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the Scala community :)

I concur with other comments, `Seq` and `List` tend to be recommended since they're immutable (much preferable especially in a recursive setting) and efficient.

It's doable with `Array` though, your code is almost working, all I had to add was giving a name to the `_*` capture (that's what the `rest@` is doing), which is then an instance of `Seq[Array]`,  s.t. I could re-use it in the recursive call:

```
  def countErased(sorted: Array[Array[Int]], acc: Int): Int = {
    sorted match {
      case Array() | Array(_) => acc
      case Array(h, n, rest@_*) =>
        if (n(0) < h(1)) {
          countErased(h +: rest.toArray, acc + 1)
        } else {
          countErased(n +: rest.toArray, acc)
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're actually pretty close. You just need to remember that the `sorted` variable is still available to you and it contains what you need to construct the next `Array`.

```
def countErased(sorted: Array[Array[Int]], acc: Int): Int =
  sorted match { 
    case Array() | Array(_) => acc
    case Array(h, n, _*) =>
      if (n(0) < h(1))  countErased(h +: sorted.drop(2), acc+1)
      else              countErased(     sorted.tail,    acc)
  }
```

As mentioned, it's pretty inefficient to manipulate arrays in this manner but if you're stuck with `Array[Array[Int]]` this will work.